# Keeping ListBox selections in session on a postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, listbox, listboxitems

As you can see below, i know how to do it for one selection, but this only works for the most recent single selection, i want to do it for several selections made.

```
Session["SelectedListItem"] = this.LstRecipients.SelectedValue;

if (Session["SelectedListItem"] != null)
{
    this.LstRecipients.SelectedValue = (string)Session["SelectedListItem"];
}
```

How can i store multiple selections made in a listbox in session and then reselect these selections on postback?

Comment: instead of storing a string in session, just add each selected value into an array of string and then store that array in session. On a postback retrieve the array from session and apply the values. OR (i don know the exact use case) activate ViewState for the Listbox. It should keep states across postbacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store anything in the session, so you can store it as `string[]` or `List<string>`:

```
string[] selectedValues = this.LstRecipients.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(i => i.Selected)
    .Select(i => i.Value)
    .ToArray();
Session["SelectedItemValues"] = selectedValues;

/* on next postback you can retrieve the values in this way: */
var selectedValues = Session["SelectedItemValues"] as string[];
if (selectedValues != null)
{
    foreach(ListItem item in this.LstRecipients.Items)
       item.Selected = selectedValues.Contains(item.Value);
}
```

Comment: I am getting issues with

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' to 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection

AND

System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<TResult>(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: AND

System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and no extension method 'Contains' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Comment: @AndyKirkpatrick; that's LINQ so you need `using System.Linq`.